# MATLAB - set/get access on fields of a struct?

Tags: oop, matlab

Suppose I have the following class:

```
classdef myClass
    properties
        Globals = struct(...
            'G1', 1,     ...
            'G2', 2      ...
        );
    end
    methods
         % methods go here
    end
end
```

I use the struct because there are other properties that are structs.

Is there any way to provide a setter for a field of the struct? Naively providing

```
function obj = set.Globals.G1(obj, val)
    obj.Globals.G1 = val; % for example
end
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define the set-method for the entire struct (see below). Alternatively, you can define a class for "Globals", which will look and feel like a structure for most practical purposes (except that you can't misspell field names), and which can implement its own set/get methods for its properties.

```
function obj = set.Globals(obj,val)

%# look up the previous value
oldVal = obj.Globals;

%# loop through fields to check what has changed
fields = fieldnames(oldVal);

for fn = fields(:)' %'#
   %# turn cell into string for convenience
   field2check = fn{1};

   if isfield(val,field2check)
      switch field2check
      case 'G1'
         %# do something about G1 here
      case 'G2'
         %# do something about G2 here
      otherwise
         %# simply assign the fields you don't care about
         obj.Globals.(field2check) = val.(field2check);
      end
   end
end
end %# function
```

Comment: That's kind of what I figured, but I figured I would ask. The issue I run into with the Globals class is I have several "peer" classes that all inherit the requirement to have a Globals struct, but what's inside that struct can be different. Is there a way to create dynamic setters/getters?

I just learned how to use dynamic properties,

Comment: @strictlyrude27: If the superclass defines the property, then it also has to define the set/get methods. However, these set/get methods can call e.g. methods called "setGlobal" and "getGlobal", which in turn can be overloaded. Personally, I have gone with dynamic properties in a similar case, but experience shows that unless you really need dynamic properties, it's better to not risk discovering Matlab bugs.

Comment: All I wanted to do with dynamic setters was to do type-checking - my intent is to treat this object as a struct and nothing more..

Comment: @strictlyrude27: Don't get me wrong: It usually works perfectly fine to add `Globals` as a dynamic property, to which you add your common set-method for type-checking. Just make sure that you also use a loadobj method to make sure the set-method is still remembered next time you load the object.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I've never had to deal with that before; time to do some reading..